# I have a SQL job that sends an e-mail. Can I make it run a program instead?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I set up a job, and in Job Properties > Notifications I checked E-mail When the job fails.

I'm wondering if instead of this e-mail, I can make it run an .exe or similar with the details. The reason is I have a piece of custom monitoring software I wrote for other applications, and I want the events to go through that instead.

Is this possible somehow? Or should I write to the event log and just try to parse it? What is net send, could that do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can setup a Job Step that only runs if the previous Step fails. Make that run an .exe?

Comment: That sounds promising! Thanks, I am a bit new to all this stuff.

Comment: You could have a step that executes a powershell or cmd script

Comment: Cheers you have answered in the comments :)

Comment: Another thing is to write the failure to windows event log. Most of the monitoring tools tend to look in the event logs for failure reporting.